Changing listen_addresses on PostgreSQL won't work
I am running Postgresql 17 on a RHEL 8.8 server and want to connect from a remote terminal server using a database client such as BeaverDB. However, I can't connect (I keep getting a "Connection refused: connect" from the client) and it seems that this is because I can't make the database server listen to external addresses as described in the Postgresql documentation:

I start psql and determine the relevant config file using the following command:
select * from pg_settings where name = 'config_file';

I edit the relevant line in the config file from
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
to
listen_addresses = '*'


and I save and close the file.

I restart the database system using
sudo systemctl restart postgresql-17


but I have also tried restarting the entire machine.

When I use psql again and type
select * from pg_settings where name = 'listen_addresses';


it still says localhost.
I know that there are several other threads with very similar questions but none contain a solution. What am I doing wrong here?

The configuration file is not the only place where listen_address can be specified; perhaps it's overridden on the postmaster command line (as one of many possibilities).

@mustaccio the command postmaster returns "command not found". Looking at the documentation I think the program might not even be part of postgresql-17.
However, I'd like to stress that this is a fresh installation of postgresql. Nobody has made any adjustments.

select source,sourcefile,sourceline from pg_settings where name = 'listen_addresses'; will give a much more accurate answer where the parameter was configured than config_file

If changing listen_addresses in postgresql.conf and restarting the server won't change the setting, but setting the parameter on the command line when you start the server does the trick, the parameter must be set on a level that overrides postgresql.conf but is overridden by command line parameters.
That leaves only one conclusion: the parameter must have been set using ALTER SYSTEM.  To fix the problem is a persistent way, run
ALTER SYSTEM SET listen_addresses = '*';

and restart PostgreSQL.

Thanks, this solved the issue for good, I think! It's crazy that a fresh install of postgresql would be his far off the setup documentation.

If that is a fresh install, the installer did something strange. Are there other settings in postgresql.auto.conf?

Okay, I kind of resolved the issue.
For some reason, the config file is ignored. However, you can set the parameter using the program 'postgres' and won't even have to restart the service or the entire machine.

Stop the running instance (might not be necessary but that's what I did): sudo systemctl stop postgresql-17
Start a new instance manually using /usr/pgsql-17/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/17/data from the bash command line (provided your folder structure match mine; the first path is the path to the "postgres" executable and the latter is the path to your database directory where the config file is located).
Execute /usr/pgsql-17/bin/postgres -c listen_addresses='*' from a command line. This will change the parameter at runtime. For me the remote connection became unblocked instantly.


Running systemctl cat postgresql-17 might be illuminating.

There are a couple of things to verify about this issue.
One is to confirm if PostgreSQL is using the correct configuration file from the OS:
$ ps aux |grep postgres |grep config_file

Also, is there anything in the log files? You can also run this command:
$ journalctl -u postgresql-17

Finally, is SELinux enabled?
$ getenforce

This could avoid taking changes from the file.
